# i am using node for a CLI but whenever i run my code i get a status 400 error

Tags: node.js, axios, command-line-interface

```
require("dotenv").config();
var keys = require("./keys.js");
const axios = require('axios');
const moment = require('moment');

var liriCommand = process.argv[2]




switch (liriCommand) {
case 'concert-this':
    concert()
    break;
case y:
    // code block
    break;
default:
// code block
}



function concert() {
var artist = '';
var nodeArgs = process.argv;
axios.get("https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/" + artist + "/events?app_id=codingbootcamp")
    .then(function (response) {
        for (var i = 3; i < nodeArgs.length; i++) {

         artist = artist + ' ' + nodeArgs[i]

        }
        console.log(artist)
        console.log(response.data[0])
        console.log(response.data[0].venue.name)
        console.log(response.data[0].venue.city + ', ' + response.data[0].venue.region)
        console.log(moment(response.data[0].datetime).subtract(1, 'days').calendar())
    })
```

}

### What i am trying to accomplish?

*I am trying to prevent my cli from taking each argv as its own separate value.. Instead i want argv[3] and so forth to be one string.. I have this accomplished in my for loop but i am now getting a status 400 error code and i am not sure how to take that information to figure out the problem?

Error: Request failed with status code 400
*

Comment: You are passing an empty string as `artist` into the URL. A 400 error is an HTTP request error, meaning Bad Request. The problem is that you are sending a request to an invalid URL because you're leaving the artist part blank. You need to set the `artist` variable before you make the request.